# How to calculate the exact probability $p$ at which maxima occurs in the curves in an infinite system?

Tags: graph-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, st.statistics, statistical-physics, percolation

I'm writing with respect to this paper: [Khatun, Dutta, and Tarafdar - "Islands in Sea" and "Lakes in Mainland" phases and related transitions simulated on a square lattice](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjb/e2017-80365-3)

Here's a link to the [PDF version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onBqzq50ApMzyvgMYekvjXdUXRbuhoZN/view).

The following graph shows the number of clusters (black and white respectively) per unit area for any $p\in [0,1]$, where $p$ is the probability of a square being black, for different system sizes ($L=8/16/32/64/128/256$ units). (Please read the abstract I linked for a brief explanation of the type of system we're dealing with.)

[image]

Is there any method to exactly calculate the $p$, for which the maxima of the curves (of black clusters, and white clusters) occur when $L\to\infty$ ?

Yes, I know that I can do numerical testing and then use extrapolation, but I don't want to do that as extrapolation often predicts values with large amount of error.

Comment: If it's not possible to exactly obtain the limiting value, I'd be interested in knowing the mathematical reason as to why it will be not possible. Maybe I should mention that in the question? @CarloBeenakker

Comment: I've computed the graphs for $L=1000,5000,10000$ as well. All of them seem to maintain the sigmoidal nature. So just from intuition (nothing else), I *think* the limiting graph would have a similar nature with a maxima somewhere before $p=0.5$ for the black cluster graph and somewhere after $p=0.5$ for the white cluster graph.

Comment: May I may please know the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I don't quite understand what type of answer you are hoping for: in the cited paper the functional form for the maximum is assumed to be $p_{\rm max}(L)=p_{\infty}+c/L$, and a fit gives the two parameters $p_{\infty}$ and $c$, resulting in a $L\rightarrow\infty$ limit of $p_\infty= 0.165$ for the black cluster and $p_\infty= 0.839$ for the white cluster; what else is there to say about this problem?

Comment: I clearly mentioned that I'm not looking for solutions which use numerical testing/computation followed by extrapolation. Which part of my question is not clear ? I'm looking for a method to calculate the limiting value of $p$ accurately. Moreover, in the paper the authors have also used the method of extrapolation to estimate $P_{c1}$ and $P_{c2}$ by extrapolation which turned out to be horribly wrong. I later found the mathrmatical proof that $P_{c1}=0$ and $P_{c2}=1$ which is far different than what comes from regression and extrapolation. @CarloBeenakker

Comment: In general there are very few models of this sort where $L \to \infty$ limits can be computed exactly, unless they are either trivial (say $p=0$ or $p=\infty$) or determined by a symmetry.

Comment: Are there at least any numerical methods to predict the "range" in which the maxima $p$ would lie in the limiting case? @RobertIsrael

Comment: I thought you weren't interested in numerical extrapolation?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I meant that since you mentioned that there are very few models of this sort where the limiting value can be predicted, I guess the second best option would be to estimate $p$ with a maximum permissible error of $\pm 0.01$. In the paper they have done the extrapolation but their predicted value doesn't seem to be correct since when I computed the graphs for L=1000 the maxima points were outside their predicted range.

Comment: That is for $L=10000$ the value of maxima for black clusters came out to be less than $0.165$ while for for white clusters it came out to be greater than $0.839$. So surely their extrapolation is wrong. But please let me know if you have some more accurate extrapolation method in mind.