# Why do larger random matrices maximize their number of clusters with lower densities?

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, random-matrices

Consider a matrix whose elements are independently assigned a value $1$ with probability $p$ and a value $0$ with probability $1-p$.

Define a *cluster* of cells as a maximal connected component in the graph of cells with the value of $1$, where edges connect cells whose rows and columns both differ by at most $1$ (so up to eight neighbors for each cell).

I numerically plotted the number of clusters vs. the probability $p$, for matrices of size $8\times 8, 16 \times 16, 32 \times 32, 64 \times 64, 128 \times 128, 256 \times 256.$  The results came out like:

Plot: Number of clusters per unit area vs. probability p for different L's:
[image: Plot: Number of clusters per unit area vs. probability p for different L's]

**Questions:**

- **Why are the maxima further left for larger matrices — why do larger matrices achieve their highest expected numbers of clusters with smaller values of $p$?**
- Has there been any study or is it possible to derive a formula which takes in $p$, size of cluster and size of the matrix as input and outputs probability of that size of the cluster existing? And/or are there any interesting results regarding this?
- As we increase from $p$ from 0, we start with isolated $1$'s popping up as individual clusters in a matrix filled with $0$'s. As $p$ increases larger clusters tend to form. The  $p$ with the maximum number of clusters seems to occur when the joining of clusters overtakes the formation of new clusters. Is there any other way to explain the occurrence of the maxima which I'm missing? Are there other noteworthy features of the maxima of the graphs?
- Here's a related question which I had asked earlier: [How to calculate the exact probability  p  at which maxima occurs in the curves in an infinite system?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294961/how-to-calculate-the-exact-probability-p-at-which-maxima-occurs-in-the-curves)

Comment: That sounds about right. As $p$ gets larger smaller clusters join into larger ones. By the time $p$ is at $\frac{1}{2}$ (maybe sooner) there should be one giant cluster and some tiny clusters. You should be able to show that for $p \ge \frac{1}{2}$ the prob that a cell is in a giant cluster is at least (say) $\frac{2}{3}$. Have you considered estimating the number of cells in a cluster of a certain size.

Comment: @Mike Indeed, I have made the plots of size distributions of clusters for p ranging from 1 to 100 (integer). You seem to be right in the sense that as p increases there is a tendency to form larger clusters. But, I'm not sure what method you would employ to show that for $p\geq 1/2$ the probability that a cell is in a giant cluster is $2/3$.

Comment: @Mike Will you be able to show that how you're thinking of getting that $2/3$ result explicitly if I ask that as a new question?

Comment: I can try. Meanwhile I was just doing a back of the envelope calculation in my head. Let c be a cell and for each positive integer r let $X_r$ be the cells in the same cluster as $x$ in a box $B_r$ of length $2r$ in both dimensions centered around $c$. Then likely the vertices of $X_r$ will have some random distribution around $B_r$ and will have (say) $N_r \min \{r, 3|X_r|/2\}$ neighbors in $B_{r+1}$ . So $X_{r+1}$ is likely to be at least $.9pN_r$ which is either larger than $|X_r|$ or close to $r$ for $p \geq 3/4$

Comment: So I am really not sure of the exact probability that there would be a giant component and so I cannot guarantee a giant component likely for the specific value of $p = 1/2$ (sorry). But my thinking was along the lines of the analysis of the size of the components of Erdos-Renyi graphs....checking that out may be useful

Comment: @Mike Interesting! Could you please expand upon that in an answer? (If you wish I could make another thread regarding the size distribution question). You can keep updating the answer if you happen to stumble upon any new facts. At the moment I'm trying to collect all the related studies which have been done. (BTW I'm just an undergrad in physics, and this is a part of a personal research project; so it might take me a while to absorb what you're writing. But I'll try my best.)

Comment: I will try to expand upon this tomorrow. Meanwhile have you googled Erdos-Renyi graphs giant component? You might find that useful too. The underlying math is nice, and I do believe that the proofs are accessible to undergraduates.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! That would be very helpful. And yes, I am going through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_component

Comment: @Mike One problem is that the $p$ here is the probability of a node being $1$, rather than the probability of the existence of an edge, unlike the Erdős–Rényi model.

Comment: @Mike I asked that as a separate question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298758/is-the-erdős-rényi-giant-component-result-applicable-here