# Can this particular random matrix model be converted/related to any existing graph theory model?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, random-matrices

### Context:

This a sequel to the question: [Is the Erdős–Rényi giant component result applicable here?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298758/is-the-erd%C5%91s-r%C3%A9nyi-giant-component-result-applicable-here)

> Consider a matrix whose elements are independently assigned a value
>   $1$ with probability $p$ and a value $0$ with probability $1-p$.
>
> Define a *cluster* of cells as a maximal connected component in the
>   graph of cells with the value of $1$, where edges connect cells whose
>   rows and columns both differ by at most $1$ (so up to eight neighbours
>   for each cell).
>
> Is it possible to reformulate this matrix model to match the
>   Erdős–Rényi graph model? I was wondering whether the [Giant
>   component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_component) result will
>   be applicable for this model and whether it will be possible to
>   reframe this problem to match the Erdős–Rényi model. I think they're
>   related but not sure exactly how. One problem is that the $p$ here is
>   the probability of a node being 1, rather than the probability of the
>   existence of an edge, unlike the Erdős–Rényi model.

According to [@Ben Barber's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/298789/123818):

> In these situations, you typically expect behaviour that, at least on
>   a very coarse level, mirrors that observed in Erdős–Rényi random
>   graphs.  However, even for the more closely related bond (edge)
>   percolation (where adjacent vertices are connected independently with
>   probability $p$) the specifics of the results and the techniques used
>   to prove them different enough that neither result is a simple
>   application of the other.
>
> The essential difference is that vertices in lattices start out much
>   further apart than vertices in a complete graph $K_n$.  It's easier
>   for vertices to be isolated (as the maximum number of vertices they
>   could possibly be adjacent to is lower) and also easier to separate
>   off large clumps of vertices from the rest of the graph: you only need
>   to find an empty ring of vertices surrounding a cluster, rather than
>   an enormous bipartite subgraph which happens to contain no edges.  The
>   end result is that percolation in lattices is typically studied **at
>   much higher values** of $p$ than the Erdős–Rényi process—constant $p$
>   rather than $p \approx 1/n$—and different probabilistic tools are of
>   use for studying the random variables that arise.

Further, [@Simon L Rydin Myerson](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298758/is-the-erd%C5%91s-r%C3%A9nyi-giant-component-result-applicable-here) says:

> On a casual inspection, I cannot actually find an example where
>   diagonal connections (cells connected only at their corners) are
>   permitted, as in your question.

### Question:

It seems that random matrix model, in this case, cannot exactly be modelled as an Erdos-Reyni graph.

**So, basically, my question is, can this particular random matrix model be related to any existing graph theory model leaving aside the Erdos-Reyni model (where diagonal connections are permitted)?**

**I'd actually be interested to know if there are some existing results about *why* giant clusters are formed in such square grids beyond a certain value of $p$ (I'm trying to make an analogy with the [giant component formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_component) in Erdos Reyni graphs).**

P.S: Please note that this is **NOT A PERCOLATION THEORY PROBLEM**. Percolation theory is concerned with the formation of spanning clusters, which is not what I meant by "giant component". A "giant component" need not necessarily be a spanning cluster. If all the cells leaving aside the edge cells get filled even that is a giant component without being a spanning cluster.

Comment: As mentioned in those answers, it seems your model is one in percolation theory. I recommend having a look at basic references in that subject, e.g. the book "Percolation" by Grimmett.

Comment: @j.c. I have looked through a few percolation theory books and papers. Couldn't find anything related to this particular model.

Comment: @JamesMartin I'm a bit confused by your comment. Firstly you say that "It absolutely is a percolation model (specifically, a site percolation model)" and then you say that "percolation theory absolutely does concern itself with questions such as the size of the largest cluster within a finite box". Sure, I know there are similar percolation models for an infinite square grid. But I'm concerned with the variation of the size of clusters w.r.t $p$, which percolation theory does not go into. You're right my question as of now is still vague, but I will post a more rigorous version soon.

Comment: @JamesMartin To be more general let's say that I'm interested in knowing how the probability of occurrence of different possible cluster sizes varies as $p$, increases from $0$ to $1$. For example, can mathematically calculate what would be the probability of occurrence of a size $100$ cluster in a $1000\times1000$ square grid at $p=0.40$ ?

Comment: @JamesMartin I actually want to look at the variation of the probabilities of occurence of the different possible cluster sizes as $p$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, in a finite system. Does percolation theory provide any such result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76811/discussion-between-james-martin-and-blue).

Comment: @JamesMartin Could you please have a look at this related question which I asked: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299253/proof-and-interpretation-of-the-following-percolation-theory-result-for-n-times ? j.c. did provide me the source for the result for bond percolation but I still couldn't find any similar result for site percolation

Comment: @JamesMartin Also, this question about the analogous version of site percolation: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299324/does-there-exist-any-analogous-result-for-site-percolation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your specific question, I would call your model "site percolation on the square lattice with nearest-neighbor (NN) and next-nearest-neighbor (NNN) bonds". Apparently this connectivity relationship is also called the ["Moore neighborhood"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood) in the study of cellular automata.

The paper ["Square lattice site percolation at increasing ranges of neighbor interactions" by K. Malarz, S. Galam](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0408338) estimates the percolation threshold in this and other similar graphs related to the square lattice.

Now, a few broader points about percolation theory. As you state in a comment, in the percolation theory literature there doesn't seem to be anything treating your particular question (the total number of clusters per site on this specific graph). However, I would not then brush all these references aside. The way to look at these results is not individually but as part of a bigger picture. Indeed, for any mathematical result, you should look at the proofs to see whether the techniques used can be generalized to other cases; e.g. can something stated for the triangular or square lattice be adapted to your graph?

In percolation (and many other models coming from statistical physics), there actually is a more profound big picture, the "[universality principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory#Universality)", where certain features (typically exponents which appear in scaling functions) are believed to depend only on the dimensionality of the graph and not its local details. This is a topic of active research, so much of what is out there is only conjectural; however it has proven to be of enormous value in seeking out new results and connections. Chapter 9 of Grimmett's book "Percolation" might be one place to start reading, though it may only make sense if you know the definitions from earlier chapters.

In that spirit, I can recommend [this paper of Mertens, Jensen and Ziff](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.00644) which discusses the features of the "number of clusters per unit area" from this point of view. Perhaps you could try to see what their results suggest about your graph and then see if you can adapt their methods to your case.

**update in response to edit**:

You still seem to object to my suggestion to dig deeper into percolation theory. I will address your concerns once more here.

It is indeed true that one of the classical definitions of the percolation phase transition is based on the appearance of *spanning* clusters. However, if you have a look at Grimmett's book, or most other rigorous mathematical sources, you will see that the modern definition of the critical probability there is in terms of the existence of an infinite open cluster. (Finite, large systems are related to this limit by the theory of "finite-size scaling").

[The probability of the existence of a cluster spanning two given sides of a large box, or more generally, two arbitrary boundary segments, is also known as the "crossing probability" and there are beautiful results about it in 2D by Cardy and Smirnov which is explained in Chapter 7 of the book "Percolation" by Bollobás and Riordan.]

In any case spanning clusters and giant clusters are highly correlated and one can show that they lead to the same definition of the critical probability. In a few more words, it is not hard to bound the probability of events like the one you describe in your edit and show that it goes to zero very quickly as the size of the system grows.

Note also that the paper of Mertens, Jensen and Ziff that I mention above does not rely at all on the crossing or lack of crossing of the clusters that they count. I've also just noticed that Chapter 4 of Grimmett's book is devoted to this function as well, which they call $\kappa$, "the number of open clusters per vertex".

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any result related to why there is a tendency of giant cluster formation and what the rate of it *is*, beyond a certain probability $p$ in this type of model?

Comment: I've added that part to my original question. Please check. I couldn't find any relevant result regarding giant cluster formation for Moore neighbourhoods.

Comment: Please note that by "giant component" I'm not referring to "spanning cluster" formation, which percolation theory is concerned about. I think this is a widespread confusion among all the people whom I asked this question. This is not a percolation problem!

Comment: For example if all the cells leaving aside the edge cells get filled up in a square lattice even that is a giant component which is not a spanning cluster.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, this rate is known as the "percolation probability", see e.g. figure 1.4 in Grimmett's book. For your second comment, as I said in my answer, it is possible that there is nothing explicitly written for that particular graph. However, results for other 2D graphs are likely to applicable or indicate what will be true. Your remaining comments have been addressed in my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm reading Grimmet's book. But one thing I'm a bit confused about is how exactly they are defining an "open cluster". Could you explain that definition of "open cluster"?

Comment: Open and closed are simply what you have been calling "black" and "white". Open clusters are connected components of the subgraph consisting of all vertices of the graph and all open edges. One other note: Grimmett works primarily with bond percolation models, whereas your model is one of site percolation; the differences are described in section 1.6. I would not worry too much about these differences while you are learning the basic definitions and results. Indeed, it could be a good exercise while you are reading proofs on bond percolation to try to translate them to site percolation.

Comment: Alright, I understand what they meant by infinite open cluster now. But I think my problem is slightly different. Say, can we mathematically calculate the probability of occurrence of a size $100$ cluster in a $1000\times1000$ square grid at $p=0.40$?

Comment: I actually want to look at the variation of the probabilities of occurrence of the different possible cluster sizes as $p$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, in a finite system. Does percolation theory give any result regarding that? I have been reading Grimmett's but couldn't find anything regarding that so far.

Comment: So you are essentially asking about the distribution of cluster sizes as a function of $p$. This is certainly of great interest in percolation theory but I don't believe the field has advanced to a point where it can provide you with all of the answers you seek. Instead, I think only a few of the lowest moments of this distribution have been studied: e.g. the expected size of the cluster at the origin is equal to the mean of the distribution you seek.

Comment: Furthermore, exact answers for specific finite systems are unlikely to be known or of much interest -- you will have more luck seeking out asymptotic approximations, in which case you should try to take results derived for infinite-size systems and apply finite-size scaling. All of what I've said above is focused on what is known rigorously. You might find various simulations and heuristics if you search for physics papers with terms like "cluster size distribution percolation".

Comment: "Instead, I think only a few of the lowest moments of this distribution have been studied: e.g. the expected size of the cluster at the origin is equal to the mean of the distribution you seek. " Could you please point me to the resource which states that?

Comment: Well, that comment is merely what "I think", i.e. a description of the state of my own (lack of) knowledge of the state of the art. Unless you are asking about the mean of the distribution being the expected size -- this is simply the definition of the mean.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Your answer at least set me on the right path. I've started looking through some of the standard percolation books and they do seem to have some results of interest to me. If you have time, please consider answering [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299253/proof-and-interpretation-of-the-following-percolation-theory-result-for-n-times) new question I asked. Once again, thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks, your answer had helped me quite a bit. By the way, I had understood that site percolation in an infinite lattice is defined as the probability $p$ beyond which an infinite open cluster begins to exist. But how is it defined for **finite lattices**? Is it defined in terms of spanning clusters for **finite lattices** i.e. an open cluster begins spanning from one border of the lattice to the **opposite** border? OR is it defined as when open cluster begins to span between any two **arbitrary** borders? I guess the first one would make more sense, but I'm not sure.